# How can I block an Android application to access location information through an Android application?

Tags: android, security, mobile

For example I want the user to be able to grant and deny access based on time/date/. To be able to specify the period e.g. 2 hours.

Other restriction that the user can use is: e.g. If I'm on 3G, this X
application should not be able to access my location.

If I'm on a Wi-Fi called work. This why application is able to access my location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify your Problem: You want your App "Foo" to control location access of App "Bar"? If so, is the App "Bar" written by yourself or a third party?

Comment: @Gapchoos  I donno how to start .My req is similar to this  http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/lbe-privacy-guard-for-android-monitors-access-requests-guards-privacy/ Thanx

Comment: @McFarlane Am novice to android. will u pls Explain me  little more

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml, include one or more <uses-permission> tags declaring the permissions that your application needs.

Comment: @Vandana Srivastava Thanx for editing

Comment: @BalaKumaran It's my job on StackOverflow.

Comment: @BalaKumaran the problem is, that you cannot control other apps except their author explicitly gives you access to his apps settings using deep linking or config files. So if the application which you want to restrict access to geolocation is not yours, the only way would be to root your phone so that you can do anything with it. But if you want your app to be installed on other phones as well, rooting is a no-go because it will void the warranty in most cases.

Comment: @McFarlane Thank u .any good tutorials for android encryption

Comment: @Gapchoos Thnk u .After trying I ll let you know .any tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, there are two posibillities:
If the "controlling app" and the "controlled app" are yours, just let them share a config file/database on the sd card and enable/disable geolocation according to settings there.

If the "controlled app" is not yours, there seems to be a way to control other apps persmissions on a rooted device according to [this blog post](http://www.howtogeek.com/115888/how-to-restrict-android-app-permissions/).
They only link to apps that can do this and not to a programming guide, but this may be a good starting point for further research.

Answer (score 1):

Application permission can not be modified at runtime and must be declared in the android.manifest.The only thing you could do is,put all your permissions in the manifest file nonetheless like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and then simply deciding by code when and how a user can access location.Maybe showing him an [alert dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)?

If the application you want to restrict is not yours,then i think there is not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you .But is it possible to control other apps